# Coinbase says my balance is on the Ethereum network. What does this mean?

Tags: tokens, wallets, coinbase

What does it mean when I’m on Coinbase and it says your balance is on the ethereum network?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple blockchains where tokens are stored. Your tokens are on Ethereum